# "As part of" versus "as a part of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

When should I use "as part of", and when "as a part of"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The difference between "as part of" and "as a part of" is essentially the difference between *part* and *a part*.

> As part of this community, I feel the need to express my opinion.

> Your comment is useless, as a part of my recent comments is.

In the first case, *part* is used with the meaning *an element or constituent that belongs to something and is essential to its nature*.
In the second case, *part* is used to mean *a piece or segment of something such as an object, activity, or period of time, which combined with other pieces makes up the whole*.

Other phrases uses *part*, and would have a different meaning (or no meaning) if they would use *a part*.

> We have come here to take part in a major game. (*Take part* means *join in*.)

Comment: As a native speaker, I disagree with this answer. I do not feel that the article "a" emphasizes how the part in question is essential to the whole.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the speaker/writer. If the part can be separated from the whole, use "a part."

Comment: Hi english lover Your answer is not very clear. Could you explain more what you mean and why it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the person who mentioned countability was close to the mark.

It is a question of whether we can predict the size or number of parts.

If we can predict it, then we use a qualifier; otherwise, no quantifier.

Note that articles (a, an, the) are quantifiers; also words such as "some", "any", "no", etc.

There's probably a better term than "predictable", but I think you get the drift.

---

unpredictable:

Can I have part of that pizza?

I hope to receive part of the profits.

---

predictable:

Did you have any part in what happened?

I took no part in it.

We all have a part to play in fighting the battle against crime.

We all have some part to play in fighting the battle against crime.

I liked the part where he suddenly …

Answer (score -3):

*Part* is used as both countable and uncountable, an example of the first case
is

> We spent part of our time fighting and arguing.

But there is a tendency to use *part* in the plural when it is treated as uncountable and that's why we seldom find "a part of" (but we can of course use "the part"). Example:

> Both parts are severely damaged.

Comment: I don't think you grasp 'countability' correctly; and this doesn't really respond to OP's question.