# a part vs. part

Tags: articles

**part** (mass noun) is close to "some", it means some but not all thing.

**a part** (countable) is a separate piece of something that you can combine with other pieces.

It has been always a problem for me to choose the right one.

For example:

> I think there's always **a** part of you that doubts what you're doing.

But I can say "**some** part of you always doubts," so then it is not a separate thing and then why "*a part*" was used in the sentence?

Comment: You failed to apply your own test correctly. As you say in the very first line, "some" should substitute "part", but that is not what you actually did. Instead you substituted it for the indefinite article, which proves nothing because that is always possible.

Comment: @RegDwighт: Agree, but If _you_ in the sentence refers to a group of people (y'all) than just "_part of you_" seems to be possible, because it can be substituted with _some_. "_And that is what **some of you were**. But you were washed_ ..." (1 Corinthians 6:11)

Comment: I have no clue weather I can say "_some of you_" referring to one person.

Comment: "Some of you" would imply that you are talking to a group of **several** people (plural *you*), and are referring to *some* of them, i.e. to a sub-group of the people.

Comment: Have you looked at these questions: [“As part of” versus “as a part of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/as-part-of-versus-as-a-part-of), and [Should I use an article with the word “part”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87713/should-i-use-an-article-with-the-word-part)

Answer (score 5):

The following are some of the common definitions for *[part](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/part)*

> 1. a piece or portion of a whole
> 2. an integral constituent of something ⇒ dancing is part of what we teach
> 3. an amount less than the whole; bit ⇒ they only recovered part of the money

Both *part* and *a part* can be used to refer to a discrete countable thing

> We teach several skills. Dancing is *part* of what we teach.
>
> We teach several skills. Dancing is *a part* of what we teach.

Dancing is a discrete thing but can take either construction.

And both *part* and *a part* can be used to refer to a more general portion of a thing that is not countable

> *Part* of the food [or money, or care] will be devoted to the poor.
>
> *A part* of the food [or money, or care] will be devoted to the poor.

The portion to be devoted is not defined in these sentences as comprising a specific  discrete section or item, but either construction is clear and appropriate. The addition of the article *a* may give a slight connotation that the portion may already be determined, but not necessarily.

The term *parts*, on the other hand, almost always refers to discrete items.

> Speaker A: *Parts* of our efforts have been highly successful.
>
> Speaker B: Which *parts*?