# Can I say "as a part of" here?

Tags: word-choice

> As a part of my community, I will do everything that needs be done to
>   resist the evil project of the oil company. (self-made)

I am not sure whether “as a part of” is appropriate or not, because “as part of” seems to be more idiomatic. But here I want to emphasize my existence as a individual. So can I write that “as a part of” ?

Comment: You could use either. I think "as a member of" might be better still, including that emphasis upon both individuality, and community membership.

Comment: You could go further and modify 'I' more thoroughly: 'As someone who has always held the welfare and unity of our community and the beauty of our town to be overridingly important, I ...'

Comment: possible duplicate of ["As part of" versus "as a part of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/as-part-of-versus-as-a-part-of)

Answer (score 2):

It's fine but personally I would go with:

> As a member of my community..

Comment: I wouldn't. I think 'As part of my community...' sounds perfect. but another possibility would be 'On behalf of my community...'

Comment: I agree with "on behalf of" but I did caveat my response with "personally".